# A mechanical system with coupled oscillators and dampers

Tags: vibrations, coupled-oscillators

I found here [Coupled oscillators](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/DE_Modeling_Example_SpringMass.html), the last one on this page, a system named by the author "Vehicle Suspension System". But I am not sure this modelizes a suspension for a vehicle.

I am interested to find and describe appropiate physical phenomena modelized by mechanical systems of this type and any other bibliographical references would be of help. Is it somehow related to a vibration reduction system from civil engineering?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257726035_Optimization_of_Vehicle_Suspension_Parameters_with_use_of_Evolutionary_Computation/fulltext/026a20240cf2db63b3aa93ae/Optimization-of-Vehicle-Suspension-Parameters-with-use-of-Evolutionary-Computation.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm confused about that horizontal wall at the top. If it is fixed and we discuss about a suspension of a vehicle, what could the horizontal wall actually represent? In this case, can the block m_1 be considered as the seat and m_2 as the wheel?

Comment: I don't think that this is a vehicle suspension model as you can see at my link

Comment: Yes, I have seen, it doesn't even look like a vehicle suspension.